# MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 not legal anymore?

Tags: c++, virtualquery

I am trying to query memory information using the Windows API.
I want to target both x86 and x64. So I read the docs about 
MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION and found that I needed two to do
different queries depending on the target process "bitness".

But when I query an x86 process and uses the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32
structure I get System Error Code 24. Which says the length of the command
is not legal.

But when I use the MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 version the call works for both x86 and x64 processes.
What is up with that. That is not what I understand the documentation is telling me.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366775(v=vs.85).aspx

So is this behavior portable across versions. So can anyone explain this behavior. Or is it just my system which is completly messed up?

This is the code I use:

```
class Process {
     HANDLE m_handle;

     bool Process::query_impl(RemotePointer address, void *info, size_t size) {
           return VirtualQueryEx(m_handle, address.get(), (MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION*) info, size);
     }
public:

     bool Process::query(RemotePointer address, MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64 &info) {
           return query_impl(address, &info, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION64));
     }

     bool Process::query(RemotePointer address,  MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32 &info) {
           return query_impl(address, &info, sizeof(MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION32));
     }
}
```

Thanks is advance.

Comment: I would understand that part of the documentation differently: normally, use MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION. there is no indication that this would not be legal. The error 24 would make me think that your `void *info`, or the `sizeof()` that goes with it, is mismatching. Use the 32/64 variants only if the bitness of the target process debugged is different from that where the debugging process runs (kind of remote debugging scenario)

Comment: The posted code snippet does not contain any error checking so it Is very unclear how you could ever get "system error 24".  Not implementing error checking correctly is a *very* common mistake.

Comment: could you include the part where you're calling `GetLastError` (assuming that you do) so we can make sure its an error code from `VirtualQueryEx`? according to documentation, the return value of the function is a `size_t` containing the number of bytes returned in the buffer, and the only possible error would be ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER (decimal 87), not ERROR_BAD_LENGTH (decimal 24)

Answer (score 0):

Interacting with the memory of processes with conflicting bitness represents a problem with many of the Windows API functions including this one.  VirtualQueryEx() when compiled under x86 takes a 4 byte pointer, but if you try to use it on a x64 process from a x86 program you can't give it a 8 byte pointer.

Even if you got it to work somehow, you would only be able to query the bottom ~4GB of memory

For this reason the best thing to do is compile separate binaries for each bitness and just use MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION so it resolves itself using the macros.